# What kind of jet fighter is this?

Tags: fighter, aircraft-identification, jet

I visisited Tirana, Albania the first week in August. Outside a shopping mall called "TEG" there was an old jet fighter on display. I can't recognise what make and model this is. Can anybody here help me?

PS: I'm sorry about the poor qualities of the pictures, but there was hard to find an angle with free sight and it was far darker than it appears on the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nobody is going to download zipped files from your private server, please host the pictures somewhere reputable.

Answer (score 7):

It's a Chengdu F-7. Albania only had Mig 15 and 19. Look at the shape of the vertical stabilizer, pitot and body behind the canopy.

[image]

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Albanian_Air_Force_aircraft#/media/File:Albanian_Air_Force_Chengdu_F-7A_Lofting-1.jpg)

Comment: Correct, the J-7 (F-7 is another name for the same aircraft) is the Chinese copy of the  MiG-21F.

Comment: In his autobiography, Chuck Yeager noted that the J7 had a life of around 100 hours, though the Pakistanis managed to stretch that out to about 130. Apparently, they didn't expect it to last in combat, so they went for numbers instead of longevity. Probably why that one is on display... it's worn out.